# How became my posts first rank in Google

Tags: google-plus, posts

I have a WordPress site http://www.swalifpress.com/

How to get my articles appear in the first page of search results in Google

I am an Arab from Egypt, sought to excuse me, I used translator

Comment: This is a question about search engine ranking. Not being a programming issue, it is off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Posting links to your own site looks a lot like spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for help with [Search Engine Optimization](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%86_%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%AB), you will probably be better served by posting on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

For anyone who wants the above link in english, [Search Engine Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).